# SQL Query fields change to uppercase on upload to server

Tags: mysql, query

I have just finished developing an app using CodeIgniter. When I upload it to my Host (Hostgator shared) some of the SQL text is converted to uppercase and rendering the app unusable.

In my database I have two tables client and transaction. When I upload the App to the server client and transaction is replaced with all caps. Obviously this is bad as MySQL queries are case sensitive.

At first I was uploading with FTP and thought FTP was to blame. I then zipped up the app and uploaded the archive, unpacking it on the server shell. Still no joy.

Any ideas on how to fix this? At the moment I just have to go into the server and edit my queries back to lowercase..

Cheers in advance for any ideas..

--Conor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [lower_case_table_names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) system variable, maybe it can help you.

Comment: Is this for correcting the table names within the database.

Sorry if I wasn't clear befire but it's the queries in my PHP code that are converted to uppercase once they land on my webserver.

Comment: Read the linked reference page, so you can learn what does this system variable.
Anyway are you sure that only the queries in php code are converted to uppercase?

Comment: I'll have a look this evening. I'll also chat to Hostgator support.

I'm not sure it's only the queries, I only noticed them because they break when in uppercase. I'd say it could be any code.. Strange.